# JSON made with .to_json (of a collection) in Rails model not readable jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I fetched the results of a query in the model. Next i right away added a .to_json and assumed I will get a correct JSON object. But JQuery was not able to parse the json

```
def self.get_all_specials(year)
  data_array=AttributeCalendarAnnual.find(:all, :conditions=>["created_at between ? and ?",Date.civil(Date.today.year), Date.civil(Date.today.next_year.year)], :order=>["created_at asc"])
  return data_array.to_json
end
```

But the result I get is not a valid JSON it seems.

**EDIT**
The output :

```
[{"created_at":"2012-01-17T17:38:27Z","id":1,"in_market_end_date":"2012-01-31T23:59:59Z","in_market_start_date":"2012-01-18T00:00:00Z","initiative_id":1,"is_mail_count_selected":true,"is_mailer_selected":true,"is_market_selected":true,"is_offer_selected":true,"mail_count":1,"mailer_start_date":"2012-01-25T00:00:00Z","offer_selection_end_date":"2012-01-12T23:59:59Z","offer_selection_start_date":"2012-01-09T00:00:00Z","updated_at":"2012-01-17T17:38:27Z"},{"created_at":"2012-01-17T20:21:37Z","id":2,"in_market_end_date":"2012-01-28T23:59:59Z","in_market_start_date":"2012-01-24T00:00:00Z","initiative_id":3,"is_mail_count_selected":true,"is_mailer_selected":true,"is_market_selected":true,"is_offer_selected":true,"mail_count":5,"mailer_start_date":"2012-01-30T00:00:00Z","offer_selection_end_date":"2012-01-21T23:59:59Z","offer_selection_start_date":"2012-01-09T00:00:00Z","updated_at":"2012-01-17T20:21:37Z"}]
```

Comment: Can you post what is returned from that `to_json` call?

Comment: I have edited the question to contain the output

Comment: Ok, why do you think it's not a valid JSON then? May be there's some issue with the way you're using it in your view (where it's later used b jQuery as I understand), but JSON itself looks fine.

Comment: How do you know that jQuery was not able to parse the json?  did you set json as the expected type in the AJAX call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are simply outputting the escaped object to your page and hoping JS will parse it this will not work because it will be interpreted as a string. Instead try feeding the string into a function like this:

```
function parseJSON(txt, escape) {
    if (escape === true) {
        txt = unescape(txt);
    }
    return new Function("return " + txt)();
}

var result = parseJSON(someString);
```